# How can I get API information about "platform post" of Facebook Insight?

Tags: api, facebook-insights

I can’t find out API information about "platform post" and “Offer” of Facebook Insight?

Overview of Facebook Insight provides Admin with post information by post type - post, photo, link, video, platform post, question, and offer. But I can’t find out related API information.

How can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Offer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/offer/

Refer to Page Offers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#offers

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know "platform post" of Facebook Insight?